# Merge two tables, inheriting values from one to another

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, union

I have two tables that I would like to display as a single result, using `UNION` or other technique.

The `ID` field relates both tables.

The second table has one field missing, so that missing value should be assumed from the first table.

The sample code below works, but is very slow for large datasets.

Is there any solution more efficient?

```
T1:                       T2:
+----+-------+--------+   +----+------+
| id | name  | town   |   | id | name |
+----+-------+--------+   +----+------+
|  1 | Alice | London |   |  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Alan  | Zurich |   +----+------+
+----+-------+--------+
```

Desired result:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | town   |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Alice | London |
|  2 | Alan  | Zurich |
|  1 | Bob   | London |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Sample code:

```
with T1 as
(
    select * from 
    (
        values
            (1,'Alice','London') ,
            (2,'Alan','Zurich') 
    ) as t (id,name,town)
), T2 as
(
    select * from 
    (
        values
            (1,'Bob') 
    ) as t (id,name)
), T2WithTown as
(
    select t2.id,t2.name,t1.town from T2
    inner join T1 on t2.id=t1.id
)

select id,name,town from T1
union
select id,name,town from T2WithTown
```

Comment: You should do upvote also for the answer that best adresses your query. this will be helpful for those users searching ofr same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data shows both tables have distinct values. So I will prefer `UNION ALL`

```
Select ID, Name, Town From T1
UNION ALL
select T2.ID, T2.Name, T1.Town
from T1
INNER JOIN T2 on T2.id = T1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
with T1 as
(
    select * from 
    (
        values
            (1,'Alice','London') ,
            (2,'Alan','Zurich') 
    ) as t (id,name,town)
), T2 as
(
    select * from 
    (
        values
            (1,'Bob') 
    ) as t (id,name)
), T2WithTown as
(
    select t2.id,t2.name,t1.town from T2
    inner join T1 on t2.id=t1.id
)

select id,name,town from T1
union
select T2.id, T2.name, T1.town
from T1
inner join T2 on T2.id = T1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name, town from t1
union 
select id,name, (select top 1 town from t1 where t1.id=t2.id) from t2
```

Comment: Don't mind for this comment. But It seems that it will be a explicit loop by using Sub Query.

Comment: ur saying that its worst than a join for example? I agree that in most of the cases it may be, but in my experience, if t2.id contains several equal values, this approach is better than a join

Comment: you will face the crash **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.** if t2.id contains several equal values

Comment: oh but that means you have more than one ID with the same code on T1. I added a top 1 on the query that will prevent it from failing